# Message Module + handling links for private messages + rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

i'm creating an application where i need to send a private message to a user and ask him/her for a confirmation on whether they would like to join or not. I have created a private message module and whenever i want to send a message, i do something like :

```
def sendMessage(attributes)
    subject = 'whatever'
    body = 'whatever'
    current_user.sendMessage(current_user, subject, body)    
end
```

Then, i get this message and print it out to the needed places, using <%=h %> for escaping stuff. My problem now is, what happens if i want to include 
's or even more importantly <%= link_to %> inside that ?

How can i insert such things to be printed out and also be careful about escaping the user provided attributes ? I was thinking of creating sort of like a partial to do this for me, but i would certainly like to hear what you think about it.

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

First off, you probably should name your method `send_message` since that tends to be the convention in Ruby and Rails.

For the question, why not do this:

```
<p><%=h user_submitted_info %> and check out this <%= link_to "Awesome Link", "/" %></p>
```

This will escape the user submitted content but leave the link_to alone. Why does the user submitted content and the link need to be in the same ERB tags?

Comment: currently, i am not using any erb templates. I just get the text provided in the function and print it out to another template, when needed. Since it prints inside a single message, the action is like viewSingleMessage and is responsible for printing any message. So handling this data from inside there is not an option. This just prints body and subject provided by sendMessage.

Comment: I don't think I understand. If you are using things like <%=h %> you are using erb.

Comment: I'm using it like <%=h @content %>. I cannot explicitly do an <%= link_to "Awesome Link", "/" %> in my case. The @content has to be something like "<%= link_to "Awesome Link", "/" %>". I'm asking how to do that.